# SLAM without odometry: gmapping or hector_slam?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, hector, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am looking for a SLAM that does not require odometry to perform, only laser scans. I have noticed 2 solutions so far: gmapping (+laser_scan_matcher) and hector_slam.

If I am in the right direction, what are the differences between both?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35924/slam-without-odometry:-gmapping-or-hector_slam?/) by [jdelbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2007/jdelbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both gmapping/laser_scan_matcher and hector_slam are viable options that have been demonstrated to work well in different scenarios (see also this [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/11945/ros-mapping/)). It might make sense to just try both for your setup and see what works best. Depending on LIDAR type, size/characteristics of the enviroment, available computing resources and other factors you might get better results with one approach or the other.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-07**:
Stefan: Does gmapping work without odom as well?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-06-07**:
You can generate fake odometry by using the laser_scan_matcher, so using a combination of gmapping/laser_scan_matcher is method not requiring (real) odometry.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-06-07**:
Thanks Stefan :)

**Comment by [jdelbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2007/jdelbe/) on 2012-06-07**:
Thanks a lot ! Indeed I guess I will have try both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
First thing that comes into my mind is [RGBDslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam). Because it works for a hand held camera and doesn't require odometry. But gmapping uses odometry. After going through the wiki of the [hector_slam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam) it seems that it also provides SLAM without odometry. So it depends on the sensor you are using.

For Kinect sensor you may use either RGBDslam or use hector_slam after converting the kinect pointclouds into laser pointclouds.

For Laser sensor I can think of only the hector_slam.

Hope to hear some answers from people who have already used hector_slam.

Thanks, Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2016-06-08**:
I have used hector_slam for mapping using only the netao laser scanner. It was pretty straight forward. I found gmapping required moving the base much slower to get a good map than with hector.

The tutorial I used for hector http://meetjanez.splet.arnes.si/2015/08/22/neato-xv-11-to-ros-slam/